# Oracle APEX 4 Tabular Form addRow function

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-xe

I have a question on Apex 4 tabular forms. I have a form with a multi-select field on top of my form with a add button and a tabular form below it. What I need to ask is:
1. Is it possible in apex 4.x to multi-select from my select list and based on my selected items when I press the ADD button on the selectlist dynamically trigger addRow() tabularform button in Apex to pre-populate the selected values from my select list?

I have done this using pl/sql using htp.p() I created my own javascript and ajax calls to do this, its able to pre-populate the values before they can be saved into the database.

is it possible with apex and how, my measure problem is that I don't know when and how the addRow() is being used i tried browsing most documentations and blogs but I dont find a solution.

please help

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to my question, What I have done was to re-use the addRow(); functionality there by passing my json string parameters loop through the elements after they are created, assign the values, rebuild all elements.

All this happens using ajax I re-use the same apex functionality without any performance degradation, the MRU/D work as normal.

I will blog about this when i get some time just finishing my project now.

Themba Tjnas Ngobeni